# Facebook Messages from owners page into Webhooks

Tags: facebook, messaging

I have an application that can receive messages from Facebook, the application can also send messages without problem, but when I answer a messages in the Facebook platform those messages does not show on my application. Is there a special Webhook that I Should be subscribe?

This are the Webhooks im currently subscribed [subscrbied webhooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty72E.png)

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying for a long time, when a page subscribes it must have these fields

$subscribedFields = ['messages', 'message_deliveries', 'message_reads', 'message_echoes', 'messaging_postbacks'];

so when you "subscribe" your page to the app will be something like this:

GET: https://graph.facebook.com/API-VERSION/PAGE-ID/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=messages,message_deliveries,message_reads,message_echoes,messaging_postbacks